# What does "Alpha" mean in Revelation 21:6?

Tags: revelation

Revelation 21 :6-7 "And he said to me, "It is done! I am the Alpha and the Omega, the beginning and the end. To the thirsty I will give from the spring of the water of life without payment. 7. The one who conquers will have this heritage..". ESV

What "Alpha/beginning" is mentioned here:

1.The beginning of life. The only source of "the water of life"?

2.The most powerful beginning. "The one who conquers will have this heritage". He who sits on the throne reigns over other "beginnings"?

3.The beginning of the Christian story. e.g. "the Father has sent his Son to be the Savior of the world". 1 John 4:14?

4.The only beginning. Although the word "Alpha" can be made to relate to aspects of its context, essentially here it stands by itself. The only beginning because "he who was seated on the throne" is the first cause of every causal chain.

If God had not created at all then only he would exist. Neither the things called "bad and good" or anything else would exist if he was not the first cause, "bad and good" Matthew 22:10?

5. How does Alpha relate to Omega?

Comment: Letters form a means of intelligent communication from one to another, expressing concept. Therefore they should be considered in the context of '_Logos_' : the word. (Up-voted +1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Greek word "alpha" always occurs as part of the phrase "alpha and omega".  These are the first and last letters of the Greek alphabet.  As such it appears to be a Greek explanation for the very OT Hebrew expression, "First and Last".

- Isa 41:4 - Who has performed this and carried it out, calling forth the generations from the beginning? I, the LORD—the **first and the last**—I am!
- Isa 44:6 - Thus says the LORD, the King and Redeemer of Israel, the LORD of Hosts: “**I am the first and I am the last**, and there is no God but Me.
- Isa 48:12 - Listen to Me, O Jacob, and Israel, whom I have called: I am He; **I am the first, and I am the last**.

In the book of Revelation we have this:

- Rev 1:8 - “I am the Alpha and the Omega, [+TR: the beginning and the end]", says the Lord God, who is and was and is to come—the Almighty.
- Rev 1:17, 18 - When I saw Him, I fell at His feet like a dead man. But He placed His right hand on me and said, “Do not be afraid. I am **the First and the Last**, the Living One. I was dead, and behold, now I am alive forever and ever! And I hold the keys of Death and of Hades.
- Rev 21:6 - And He told me, “It is done! I am **the Alpha and the Omega, the Beginning and the End**. To the thirsty I will give freely from the spring of the water of life.
- Rev 22:13 - "**I am the Alpha and the Omega, the First and the Last, the Beginning and the End**."

Thus, the title, "the Alpha and the Omega, the First and the Last, the Beginning and the End" in the book or Revelation is taken from the title of Jehovah in the OT and applied to both God the Father and Jesus in the NT.

Therefore, the title "first and last" = "alpha and omega" is a divine title expressing eternal existence - before all things (Col 1:17) and eternal existence.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha points to the absolute beginning of aseity.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aseity

> Aseity (from Latin ā "from" and sē "self", plus -ity) is the property by which a being exists in and of itself, from itself, or exists as so-and-such of and from itself.[1] The word is often used to refer to the Christian belief that God contains within himself the **cause of himself**, is the **first cause**, or rather is simply **uncaused**

Colossians 1:17 expresses this idea of aseity:

> He is before all things, and in him all things hold together.

God created the air and us. We need air to stay alive. Take away the air and we died. God's life does not depend on anything he created. The divine life cannot die. This points to the unending of Omega.

Revelation 1:8

> "I am the Alpha and the Omega," says the Lord God, "who is, and who was, and who is to come, the Almighty."

Alpha points to eternity apart from the beginning of physical time. Omega points to eternity apart from after the end of physical time.
Alpha and Omega refer to the existence of the uncreated God. Alas, words fail us. In a sense, there is no beginning and there is no end.

Comment: Alpha and Omega come as a pair so if Alpha points to aseity how does that relate to Omega? I have put in point 5.

Comment: Good point. I added.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'eternity before' or 'eternity after'. Eternity is. It is something _other_ than time. The term _aseity_ originates from Plato, not from the bible.

Comment: Good point. I modified.

Answer (score 0):

“*How does Alpha relate to Omega?*”. Answer, it is ‘את’.

Revelation is the ‘most Old Testament like’ book in the New Testament. Well over three quarters of this book directly references the Old Testament. The Old Testament Hebrew has this ‘את’ combination in numerous locations - and it is mostly untranslated.

aleph-tav (את) are the first and last letters of the Hebrew alphabet. In Revelation, written in Greek, the first and last letters are alpha/omega. את in the Old Testament reflects Inspiration, divine inspiration.

The presence of this ‘marker’ although not translated, is always highly significant. It either centre’s many ‘truths’, that is, God giving his signature to what is said. Or is surrounds significance sections. (Starts and Ends them).

Even it’s presence *in* words is significant. The Hebrew word for truth ‘אֱמֶת’, starts and ends with aleph-tav.

So in your quoted verse...

**Revelation 21:6** *And he said to me, "It is done!*

“it is done” ends with Gods ‘mark’ - that is, that it **is** the truth. Another words, it **is** done!

Comment: Can you quote some places in the OT where ‘את’ is used?

Comment: _The Old Testament Hebrew has this ‘את’ combination 9612 times - and it is mostly untranslated._ Could you give us some substantiation, or link, or other reference, please.

Comment: @Nigel “I Am the Aleph-Tav: Unveiling Jesus in the Old Testament” - ISBN: 9781973627432.

Comment: @Dottard How about the first verse. GEN 1:1 - בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ

Comment: @Dave - are you suggesting that אֵת in Gen 1;1 as a direct object marker (an essential part of Hebrew grammar and syntax) is the signature of God???

Comment: @Dottard Not me - I take that from others who study Hebrew. The exact and precise placement of this marker throughout the Old Testament is argued to ‘reflect’ *divine* inspiration in those locations where it is found - to reflect the [true] author. Example, the ‘את’ in Gen 1:1 is both perfectly positioned and balanced - and that in itself ‘adds’ a deeper meaning (which is not translated.)

Comment: @Dave The "את" in Hebrew, if by itself, marks the next word as a definite direct object.  It is possible to have a direct object without it, but if the "את" is present, that object must always be definite (like "the" in English).  Suffixes can be added to the marker to create certain pronouns, and there are times when the marker is used to mean "with".  In all of my Hebrew lessons, including those from several Jewish instructors, none has mentioned this marker as being God's signature.

Comment: @Polyhat OK, it’s now very clear I used the wrong terminology. I’ll concede to you and Dottard. However, I do still maintain that the placement of this *marker* throughout the Old Testament reflects divine inspiration.